# Jquery Mobile - events wont bind after using $.mobile.navigate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

When I use $.mobile.navigate to change the page, the page will load but the my custom script won't bind to the elements. If I refresh the page, the custom script will load and bind to the elements. I have a select element to choose between pages:

```
<select name="calc-Nav" id="calc-Nav">
    <option value="a.php">A</option>
    <option value="b.php">B</option>
    <option value="c.php">C</option>
</select>
```

This is the event bound to the select element:

```
$("#calc-Nav").on("change", function (e) {
    var opt = $("#calc-Nav option:selected").val();
    if (opt) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.navigate(opt);
    }
});
```

Also, I link to my javascript files in the following order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the template used for all pages
This is the standard Template of each of the pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <select name="calc-Nav" id="calc-Nav">
                    <option value="Index.php">Home</option>
                    <option value="a.php">a</option>
                    <option value="b.php">b</option>
                    <option value="c.php">c</option>
                </select>
            </div>
         </div>
     <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <div id="index">
             <h1> Form goes Here. </h1>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer">
         <h1>Footer</h1>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formulas.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind them to the document

try-

```
$(document).on("change","#calc-Nav", function (e) {
    var opt = $("#calc-Nav option:selected").val();
    if (opt) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.navigate(opt);
    }
});
```

also be sure to add the link to your custom script after the jqmobile script

Comment: Still no luck. The View source looks the after the refresh. Any thoughts

Comment: @ButtScratch do you have this selectbox on each page? could you show the entire code page an js?